# How to add curly braces to indented code?

Tags: c, formatting, pseudocode

I am trying to convert a pseudo-code to C code. The pseudo-code is indented like Python. I want to convert that into curly braces. Is there a way to do it ? 
Example the pseudo-code looks like this:

```
    int my_function(int a, int b)
        int c;
        int d;
        if(a==5)
            c = 6;
            d = 7;
        else
            c = 8;
            d = 9;
        return (c+d);
```

I want to convert it into the following.

```
    int my_function(int a, int b)
    {
        int c;
        int d;
        if(a==5)
        {
            c = 6;
            d = 7;
        }
        else
        {
            c = 8;
            d = 9;
        }
        return (c+d);
    }
```

Comment: Usually people do the conversion manually, exactly as you have to produce the pseudo code sample and the second version in your post.     The point of pseudo-code is to demonstrate a concept to a human, not to a machine.  It's only in science function that a computer can take a hand-wavy, imprecise, pseudo-code description and produce functional and perfect code

Comment: I would not call that true pseudo-code since it would be entirely possible to implement an interpreter to execute that given a suitable language definition.  Pseudo-code is a method of presenting a concept or algorithm without having to be as precise or as unambiguous as if a machine were executing it.  Writing pseudocode like you have is no less effort than writing real code, so serves no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are intending to write *real* code to perform the transformation, rather then looking for a tool or editor facility, then it is simply text processing.

In (true) pseudo-code, you would do the following:

```
For each line:

  if the indentation is greater than the current level then:
    insert a line before with an opening brace at the current level, 
    increase the current level

  otherwise if the indentation is less than the current level then:
    While current level > new level
      insert a line after with an closing brace at the current level, 
      decrease the current level
```

Comment: For completeness, you might add a final step: `while current_level > 0: insert a line a closing brace at the current level and decrease the current level`

Comment: @chqrlie : Was already  doing that as you were typing your comment.  But credit where credit is due, it was the first paragraph of your answer that precipitated the change

Answer (score 1):

To turn this Python-like pseudo-code, you can insert a `{` before any line indented  more than the current one and as many `}` after the block as there are indentation levels to unwind.

There are multiple styles as to where the braces belong. The example you posted in the question tends to increase the number of lines at the expense of readability and may make some silly mistakes harder to detect, such as this:

```
    while ((c = getchar()) = EOF);
    {
       putchar(c);
    }
```

A popular alternative style has the opening brace inserted at the end of the line that commands the block (the `if`, `for`, `while`, `do` or `switch` statement) and the closing brace at the beginning of a separate line, followed by the `else` part of the `if` statement or the `while` part of the `do` statement.

Here your code modified for this style:

```
int my_function(int a, int b) {
    int c, d;

    if (a == 5) {
        c = 6;
        d = 7;
    } else {
        c = 8;
        d = 9;
    }
    return c + d;
}
```

Comment: If the point is to  render the pseudo code into machine parseable C code by machine, questions of style and errors are irrelevant- the compiler does not care how readable the code is, only whether it is syntactically correct.  If the pseudo-code contains errors, that is not for the translator to deal with perhaps - at least that is not what is being asked for  here.  In any event you are clearly expressing an opinion regarding your preferred style rather than answering the question.

Comment: @Clifford: I agree, but the question was not clearly about performing the transformation by machine. I did not just express an opinion, rather exposed some objective facts about 2 different bracing styles.

Comment: I would suggest it is subjective rather then objective, I personally (and _subjectively_) dislike the "line-saver" style and find the braces easier to match visually when they align with each other and the vertical white-space does as much as horizontal to aid readability.  There are probably as many arguments for one as the other. Either way - it is still not related to the question in hand, but rather a comment on the style used in the question.  Your first paragraph accurately and succinctly answers the question.

Comment: @Clifford: OK, I removed the subjective part *at the expense of readability*.